# fixing position of div having float:left property

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have certain boxes which I want them to be side by side. I used `float:left;margin-left:10px;` and successfully achieve my aim.

But I want to lock their positions on screen i.e. fixed w.r.t to screen and no movements according to mouse. For that I tried to use `position:fixed', it too worked, but now it created a problem.

The problem is that the two boxes are now overlapping with each other and displaced with their location.

Her is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/ETwEF/)**

```
.chatWindow {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 280px;
bottom:0;
background: #FAFAFA;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float: left;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fixed property to parent div. Try this fiddle.

**CSS**

```
.chatWindow-parent{
    position: fixed;
}
.chatWindow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
    bottom:0;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chatWindow-parent">
    <div class="chatWindow"></div>
    <div class="chatWindow"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2csBx/

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 2 different classes. Otherwise by fixing the position you are telling them to be fixed in the same location.

Need to add a parent class

**HTML**

```
<div class="chatContainer">
    <div class="chatWindow"></div>
    <div class="chatWindow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    height: 2000px;
}
.chatContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.chatWindow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ETwEF/2/

Comment: What if I have 15-20 such divs? and in my real project I do have.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the help, but you were seconds away from @jnsamines :)

Comment: Ahh I know! I didn't know you had to have more than 2 :(